# Remove default field "doc" that gets added by Couchbase while doing XDCR

Tags: couchbase, elasticsearch

We are trying to remove "doc" field which gets added on top of original document by Couchbase while doing XDCR.

For example:

Below is our sample original document :-

```
{
   "UserID": "User1",
   "FirstName": "First",
   "LastName": "Last",
   "Roles":
   [
     {
       "RoleID" : "1",
       "RoleName": "R_1"
     }
   ]
}
```

But when we do XDCR from Couchbase to ElasticSearch, Couchbase adds "doc" field which holds the original document. Below is the sample document created by Couchbase XDCR :-

```
{
   "doc":
   {
       "UserID": "User1",
       "FirstName": "First",
       "LastName": "Last",
       "Roles":
       [
         {
           "RoleID" : "1",
           "RoleName": "R_1"
         }
       ]
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to remove this "doc" field?

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 1):

Not in the current implementation - it's hardcoded. You can open a [feature request](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/issues) to make it configurable, so it will be added in the next release.